# Sass built app/builds/application.css not making it into header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, ruby-on-rails-7, cssbundling-rails

I am using the ruby Gem [cssbundling-rails](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails) and [dart-sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass) to process Sass in a Rails 7 app (and I am fairly new to Rails).

In the *package.json* file I define the `build:css` script:

```js
"build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=. --load-path=./node_modules --load-path=./node_modules/@rpf/sauce --load-path=app/assets/stylesheets/"
```

This appears to be working; I see the results of several Sass files bundled and processed into one CSS file: *app/builds/application.css*.

However I cannot see how to add this file to my page. We use Slim so I include the line

```slim
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
```

in the *app/views/components/_head.html.slim* file. That results in this fragment in the final HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application-e0cf9d8fcb18bf7f909d8d91a5e78499f82ac29523d475bf3a9ab265d5e2b451.css" />
```

If I load that file (*application-e0cf9d8fcb18bf7f909d8d91a5e78499f82ac29523d475bf3a9ab265d5e2b451.css*) into my browser I see it is an empty manifest file which starts

```
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files   
* listed below.
```

and has no files listed below.

What am I missing? How do I load the CSS that was bundled and processed from Sass files into the *app/builds/application.css* file into my Slim page?

Answer (score -1):

A simple fix is to add

```slim
link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application.css" type="text/css"
```

to *app/views/components/_head.html.slim* instead.